# How do I find the highest count of the same values with Pandas Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying finding the most popular major for each university.

Here is a sample of the table:

```
Institution   Major_Name  Count  Major
School 1      Art           2    First
School 1      English      12    First
School 1      Math          7    First
School 1      Art           6    Second
School 1      English       4    Second
School 1      Math          3    Second

School 2      Art         9
School 2      English     4
School 2      Math       13
```

I want the final outcome to look like this where the rest of the rows will disappear:

```
Institution   Major_Name   Count   Major
School 1      English       12     First
School 1      Art            6     Second
School 2      Math          13
```

Thanks in advance. Very new to using Pandas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a `groupby` on `Institution` and then apply the `max` function:

```
In [547]: df.groupby('Institution', as_index=False).max()
Out[547]: 
  Institution  Major  Count
0     School 1  Math     12
1     School 2  Math     13
```

The `as_index=False` attribute will prevent the resultant `GroupBy` object from assigning `Institution` as the new index.

---

Based on your edit: To group by `Institution` as well as `Major`, you can specify multiple columns to group by:

```
In [563]: df.fillna('').groupby(['Institution', 'Major'], as_index=False).max()
Out[563]: 
  Institution   Major Major_Name  Count
0     School1   First       Math     12
1     School1  Second       Math      6
2     School2               Math     13
```

Comment: Ah, okay thank you. Started learning Pandas... so so far only know the basic things. Okay, there's one more column though that needs to be looked at. How do I get separate max counts for first and second major? (edited table above for 1st school)

Comment: By the way I started learning pandas yesterday, so answering questions is helping me grow :)

Comment: Yay. Haha, just started learning this weekend and trying to use my skills for a data journalism project.

Comment: By the way, I've edited my answer slightly. Use `df.fillna('')` if your data frame has empty values in it.